# Jekyll adding unwanted space before and after links

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I'm learning Jekyll. I finished the step by step tutorial: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/

Variables seem to generate spaces before and after. Eg. item.name is now outputting the following:

```html
<a href="#"> Home </a>
<a href="#"> Blog </a>
<a href="#"> About </a>
<a href="#"> Staff </a>
```

Which visually puts a space after each link. Ugly and potential for styling mishaps.

Do I have to make it, not do that? Am I OCD? Or am I doing it wrong?

Reference:

_includes/nav.html

```
<nav>
  {% for item in site.data.nav %}
  <a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if page.url==item.link %}class="current" {% endif %}>
    {{ item.name }}
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

that *.current* class

```
.current {
  color: green;
}
```

_data/nav.yml

```
- name: Home
  link: /
- name: About
  link: /about.html
- name: Blog
  link: /blog.html
- name: Staff
  link: /staff.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't happen to me, but this can be fixed by adding `| strip` after `item.name` like so:

_includes/nav.html

```
<nav>
  {% for item in site.data.nav %}
  <a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if page.url==item.link %}class="current" {% endif %}>
    {{ item.name | strip }}
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

EDIT:
Seems like in OP's case, it's caused by indentation's spacings. To fix this,  you must replace any occurrence of `{{` with `{{-`, `}}` with `-}}`, `{%` with `{%-`, and `%}` with `-%}`. Here's the [reference](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/).

Comment: Hmm didn't change anything for me. Might offer a hint...

Here's the repo: <https://gitlab.com/Aronikun/aroni.co/-/tree/main/src>

Just in case I've overlooked something.

Comment: @aroni updated the answer, I run your repository on my local machine, and it worked with my new solution

Comment: And that totally fixed it. Thank you! I wonder why it would indent right out of the box...